# My JS app on Heroku gets deployed but the application shows error in the server side build

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

I deployed a Heroku app using the CLI. The code is based in JS(Node).
The log displayed the following message-

```
2020-11-19T18:13:19.981359+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-11-19T18:13:32.577655+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-11-19T18:13:35.931851+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-11-19T18:13:35.931868+00:00 app[web.1]: > server@1.0.0 start /app
2020-11-19T18:13:35.931868+00:00 app[web.1]: > concurrently "npm run server" "npm run client"
2020-11-19T18:13:35.931869+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-11-19T18:13:35.941884+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: concurrently: not found
2020-11-19T18:13:35.951483+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-11-19T18:13:35.951777+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2020-11-19T18:13:35.952007+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2020-11-19T18:13:35.952258+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2020-11-19T18:13:35.957255+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! server@1.0.0 start: `concurrently "npm run server" "npm run client"`
2020-11-19T18:13:35.957411+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2020-11-19T18:13:35.957579+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-11-19T18:13:35.957727+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the server@1.0.0 start script.
2020-11-19T18:13:35.957859+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-11-19T18:13:35.968472+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-11-19T18:13:35.968693+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-11-19T18:13:35.968767+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-11-19T18_13_35_958Z-debug.log
2020-11-19T18:13:36.042215+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-11-19T18:13:36.100527+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-11-19T18:41:07.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user riteshkumarstudy@gmail.com
2020-11-19T18:41:43.985964+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 1581c630 by user riteshkumarstudy@gmail.com
2020-11-19T18:41:43.985964+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user riteshkumarstudy@gmail.com
ll be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
2020-11-19T18:42:59.987409+00:00 app[web.1]: Server listening on port 3001
2020-11-19T18:43:00.110366+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureIndex is deprecated. Use createIndexes instead.
2020-11-19T18:43:16.984202+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=pacific-scrubland-58982.herokuapp.com request_id=e41c2163-819d-4d95-a87a-48e84acfd06e fwd="223.225.248.157" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-11-19T18:43:55.839112+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2020-11-19T18:43:55.866993+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2020-11-19T18:43:56.004273+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2020-11-19T18:43:56.057821+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-11-19T18:43:56.610979+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=pacific-scrubland-58982.herokuapp.com request_id=f941b09d-91ae-4ddb-87c1-96a66d8c8912 fwd="223.225.248.157" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-11-19T18:43:57.136454+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=pacific-scrubland-58982.herokuapp.com request_id=be1491ea-8d01-4b37-9902-6e93678ba0b6 fwd="223.225.248.157" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-11-19T18:43:58.163525+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=pacific-scrubland-58982.herokuapp.com request_id=c304480a-ca92-4bf0-9ef2-837931f38d55 fwd="223.225.248.157" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-11-19T18:43:58.312956+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=pacific-scrubland-58982.herokuapp.com request_id=7334f985-397f-4f3e-b667-99fd19831635 fwd="223.225.248.157" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

The link to the repo is https://github.com/CSAIDept/Final-Combined-Pages
Need help on what to do next?
I used the https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack to deploy this app.

Answer (score 0):

You installed `concurrently` as a dev dependency, Heroku will not install devDependency. Try adding concurrently to normal dependency in `package.json` and try again

Comment: The error is saying that concurrently module was not found